# onCLickListener in ContextMenu

Tags: android, contextmenu, onitemclicklistener

Every item of my listview must show his own context menu and till here it works.My problem is that altough it works for the first click, the once I click, the twice doesn't works but works only the longClick.
I can't understand the reason.
Please help me.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  
           @Override  
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, final View componente, int pos, long id){  
               final String titoloriga = (String) adapter.getItemAtPosition(pos);  
               Log.d("List", "Ho cliccato sull'elemento con titolo" + titoloriga+"    " +Integer.valueOf(pos)+"    "+Long.valueOf(id));
               registerForContextMenu(componente);
               componente.showContextMenu();

           } 

    }); 


}//end onCreate

 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.add("Comando1").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("menu", "1");
                return false;
            }});
        menu.add("Comando2").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("menu", "2");
                return false;
            }});
        menu.add("Comando3").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("menu", "3");
                return false;
            }});
    }//end create menu
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `onContextItemSelected()` method, like this:

```
String[] comandos = {"Comando1","Comando2","Comando3"};

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    for(int i = 0; i < comandos.length(); i++){
        menu.add(comandos[i]);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case 1:
            Log.i("menu", "1");
        .......
    }
}
```

Comment: And anothe problem occurs: I can't not even display the Log.i() inside the switch construct.